# Weather for specific date?

Tags: api, date, weather

Is there any weather api that supports query weather for a specific date(or date range)?

In my application, i need to show weather for today but last year.
I can store weather in DB for aech day since now, and next year i'll be able to show last year's data. But it's not "sexy" solutions.

Any ideas?

Comment: Whereabouts in the world are you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try Wolfram Alpha for Developers:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/developers.html

Comment: I just tried that, what an awesome suggestion. Works for dates waaay back in the past (i.e. 25+ years)

Comment: Wolfram Alpha is not really ready yet, but it is quite nice. Try searching for the weather in Amsterdam on Barack Obama's birthday :)

Comment: Excellent! I hope it can translate its results to different languages. Have to look deeper into it.

Answer (score 0):

There's something called the

- [National Digital Forecast Database (NDFD) Simple Object Access Protocol (SOAP) Web Service](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/xml/)

Try saying that 3 times.